# TypeError: Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'ConcatV2' Op have types [float32, float16] that don't all match using tensorflow mixed precision

Tags: tensorflow2.0, recommendation-engine

I'm using tensorflow-recommenders library to create a recommender, but when I try to use mixed precision, a error is raised when validating:

```
TypeError: Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'ConcatV2' Op have types [float32, float16] that don't all match.
```

It's worth mention that the model trains successfully, the problem occurs when trying to validate.
[image: user_model]

The image depicts how the user model is defined. Item model is similar. The two-tower model is this:

```
class two_tower_model(tfrs.Model):
def __init__(self, user_model, item_model, items_dataset):
    super().__init__()
    self.user_model = user_model
    self.item_model = item_model
    self.items_dataset = items_dataset
    self.task = tfrs.tasks.Retrieval(
        metrics=tfrs.metrics.FactorizedTopK(
            candidates=self.items_dataset.batch(2048).map(item_model)))
    
def compute_loss(self, features, training=False):
    user_embeddings = self.user_model({feature: features[feature] for feature in ["USER_EMBEDDING", "event_data"]})
    item_embeddings = self.item_model({feature: features[feature] 
                                       for feature 
                                       in ["ITE_ITEM_ID", "ITE_DOM_DOMAIN_ID", "CAT_CATEG_ID", "ITE_ITEM_TITLE"]})
    
    return self.task(user_embeddings, item_embeddings, compute_metrics=not training)
```

I don't know if the problem is related with the model construction or with the mixed precision policy. I'm using TFv2.3.1 and TFRSv0.3.2.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delayed answer but I think it's better to share my solution here maybe this answer helps someone.

This error is caused by a number of reasons. But in my case, it is due to different Dtypes and shape issues. I was getting the following error

```
TypeError: Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'ConcatV2' Op have types [float32, float32, int64] that don't all match.
```

This error is because of this line of code

```
    return self.ratings(tf.concat([user_embedding, cuisine_embedding, count], axis=1))
```

I solved this by first converting my count(Tensor) to float32 and then reshaping it to [-1, 1] to make it a rank 2 matrix.

```
return self.ratings(tf.concat([user_embedding, cuisine_embedding, 
                                   tf.reshape(tf.cast(count, tf.float32), [-1, 1])], axis=1))
```